# Insert a dash between columns in a table?

Tags: html, css, csv

I would like to make a table with three columns, that is taking data from a csv. However,  I would like to insert a dash between two columns so instead of

**Fruit Animal Colour**

Apple  Dog   yellow

banana  Cat   blue

it would be

**Fruit Animal Colour**

Apple - Dog   yellow

banana -  Cat   blue

Any suggestions would be great!

Comment: Try to make  use of ```border-right: 1px dashed #000;```. Incase you want to have bigger dashed. Increase the side of border. The distance between dash will be grow.

Comment: Thanks @HimanshuSaxena - that's almost it, but not exactly as its vertical not horizontal

Comment: that's why its ```border-right```. If you need horizontal then it should be ```border-bottom```. Or please upload an expected output image. That would be giving more clarity what's the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) pseudo-element together with [`nth-child(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child).
Check the snippet below for a demo.

```css
table tr td:nth-child(2)::before {
  content: "- ";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Fruit</th>
    <th>Animal</th>
    <th>Colour</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Dog</td>
    <td>yellow</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>banana</td>
    <td>Cat</td>
    <td>blue</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @msassen , that seems to do it , and yes I do want to use a table - one last question, I wonder if it is possible to have the dash(es) appears directly under each in the column regardless of the length of a word.

Comment: @heroZero I'm having trouble understanding "appears directly under each in the column" but I'm guessing you mean you want the dashes to align vertically. I'll update the answer to do that.

Comment: My apologies msassen, 'dashes to align vertically' is exactly what I meant!